# How to wait for all WebElements to disappear in Haskell WebDriver client?

Tags: haskell, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm writing a test using [Haskell WebDriver client](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/webdriver-0.6.0.3).

I have a page, which - when it is initially loaded - contains several "panel loading" animation elements. Before starting interaction with the page, I would like to wait for these elements to disappear.
How do I express this logic using [Test.WebDriver.Commands.Wait](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/webdriver-0.6.0.3/docs/Test-WebDriver-Commands-Wait.html)?

In other words, I would like a Haskell equivalent of the following code expressed using Java WebDriver's API

```
private void waitForPageLoad() {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 15/*wait timeout in seconds*/, 100/*poll interval in miliseconds*/)
     .until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector(".panel_loading")));
}
```

.. so that I can later use it inside the WD monad like:

```
doStuff :: WD ()
doStuff = do
  openPage "blabla"
  waitForPageToLoad -- how to define this?
  input <- findElem $ ById "someID"
  --etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't actually run this, but the following code type checks.

To wait until there are no elements with class "panelLoading" try something like:

```
doStuff' :: WD ()
doStuff' = do
  openPage "blabla"
  waitWhile 30 $ findElem (ByClass "panelLoading")
  ...
```

Explanation:

`waitUntil` will repeat an action until it succeeds. An example (from the `onTimeout` documentation) which waits until there is an element having CSS class "class" and then returns its text:

```
waitUntil 5 (getText <=< findElem $ ByCSS ".class")
```

`findElem` will throw a `NoSuchElement` exception if it fails.

`waitWhile` inverts the wait condition so you can use it in conjunction with `findElem` to wait until there no elements of a certain class / css selector / etc.

You can create a custom wait condition by using `unexpected`, e.g.:

```
-- wait until there are an even number of elements having class "class"
waitUntil 5 $ do elems <- findElems $ ByCSS ".class"
                 if (odd (length elems))
                   then unexpected "odd number of elements"
                   else return ()
```

Also see `waitUntil'` and `waitWhile'` to control the poll frequency.